# AngularJS - Unit Test with $timeout

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a directive that look like this:

```
angular.directive('myDirective', ['$compile','$timeout', function($compile,$timeout){
    console.log("myDirective compile");
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            console.log("myDirective before timeout");
            $timeout(function(){
                console.log("myDirective after timeout");
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

When I do unit test with Karma-Jasmine, I get the `LOG` output of `myDirective compile` and `myDirective before timeout`. But no output for `myDirective after timeout`

How can I get the `$timeout` function to run in unit test?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `flush` method on the `$timeout` service to flush the timeouts that you set. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout

Note that this is available in ngMock and you therefore need to include angular-mocks. (I'm fairly sure you have but just in case.)

See the test below for an example.

```
describe('my directive test', function () {
    var element;
    var scope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
        element = '<my-directive></my-directive>';
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        element = $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        spyOn(console, 'log').and.callThrough();
    }));

    it('should not log the timeout', inject(function ($timeout) {
        expect(console.log).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith('myDirective after timeout');
    }));

    it('should log after timeout', inject(function ($timeout) {
        $timeout.flush();

        expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myDirective after timeout');
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
$timeout.flush(amount)
```

In your tests, with `amount` the amount of time you want to pass.